# Building a Naive Bayes classier based on training set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I went through the sentdex nltk tutorial on youtube and modified his code slightly to build a text classifier or negative and positive comments.
I am using a training set of positive and negative comments then based on the 5000 most common words building the classifiers.

My question: given my current code using the classifiers I am using, how could I improve the accuracy of my results?

1. Is there one classifier that is that much better than the others?
2. Can slightly tweaking my code improve the accuracy somewhat?

https://gist.github.com/egimple/08e8737140cc93604ef2541d803e8987

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.
I hope that this question meets the stackoverflow standards if it does not please comment below and I will try to edit the question

Comment: You could start by mentioning your choice of features and the accuracy you're achieving so far. But I'm afraid your question is a bit too open-ended for this site; you will have a better question if you focus on one aspect that you are unsure about, and provide code snippets, with sufficient context, if appropriate. My advice would be to experiment for yourself: think about additional features and try adding them; try a few different classifier engines from the nltk's offerings.

Comment: Shameless plug: https://github.com/alvations/bayesline/blob/master/bayesline/discriminate.py

Comment: thanks alvas I was going through your code but I wasnt sure how it works exactly if you could provide a brief explanation that would be great.

Comment: I have posted this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150347/traning-and-testing-of-sentiment-analysis

Comment: I have posted this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150347/traning-and-testing-of-sentiment-analysis  alvas if you choose to either explain your code here or there I would accept that as an answer and I have seen your explanations elsewhere and they are very good I am just very knew to sklearn and in general doing sentiment analysis properly